# Cloud Endpoints Generated library not found

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am creating a backend GAE project with Cloud Endpoints. I want also to create an Android application that will consume these endpoints, and I found in the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android) that I have to copy the java source classes to my Android project to access to the endpoints. I really don't like this approach thinking in the case that I am developing the endpoints for a external client (I don't want to give them my source code, I prefer just give them a jar library to avoid complexity).

I found reading the README file also generated with the endpoints that `The generated service-specific library can be found in the top level directory
of the zip file:
google-api-services-noteendpoint-v1-rev20130920182043-1.16.0-rc.jar`. But this jar is not generated anymore.

So, copying the source classes is the only way to pass the access to the endpoint to the Android project? Where is this jar that once was supposed to be created?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer, the jar is not generated but can be generated by maven. The endpoints created has maven structure and you only have to package it to get the final jar. Tested and working.

Answer (score 0):

On eclipse, with Google plugin, clicking on the appengine project you can select:
Google->Generate Cloud Endpoint Client Library, you need to have an associated android project. You can create a android associated project, selecting, when creating a new project: AppEngine Connected Android Project.